# Why is my Fragment reference persisting upon rotation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, landscape-portrait, screen-rotation

I have a simple Activity with two layouts: one for portrait, another one for landscape.

- The Portrait one contains a simple ListView.
- The Landscape layout contains the same ListView, plus an additional fragment added in XML.

I sketched it in a piece of paper, in an attempt to make it even clearer. Forgive my awful drawing skills:
[image: problem_description]

**So what's the matter?**

When the Activity is first started (no matter if in Portrait or Landscape), I attempt to get a reference to the Fragment programmatically, like this:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map_fragment);
        if (mapFragment != null) {
           // ...
        }
}
```

Two options here:

1. The user started the Activity in Portrait. Therefore no Fragment exists, so *mapFragment is null*.
2. The Activity was started in Landscape mode. In this case a reference to the Fragment is actually found and *mapFragment is NOT null*.

Nothing new here.

Now... what would one expect if the Activity were started in Landscape -> went to Portrait (user rotates phone)? **What would mapFragment contain?** null? No.

I was expecting mapFragment to be null upon rotating to Portrait, where the Fragment doesn't exist. But [looking at the docs for the findFragmentById() method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#findFragmentById(int)), we can see this:

> [...] searches through fragments that are currently added
>   to the manager's activity; **if no such fragment is found, then all
>   fragments currently on the back stack associated with this ID are
>   searched**.

Cool, so I understand I was mistaken. My Fragment once existed when in Landscape, and when the user rotates back to Portrait the Fragment still exists in the Back Stack. So it's a matter of wiping out the fragment back stack, or is it? Yes, this must be it.

Alright, let's override the onSaveInstanceState() where we'll be able to clear the back stack (*because, surprise surprise... this can't be done after the onSaveInstanceState() method gets triggered!*). Let's get to it:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, getSupportFragmentManager().POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

**Phew! We must be done here. Let's debug the app and check it out!**

1. We start the Activity in Portrait. Check mapFragment. Returns null.
2. We rotate to Landscape. Check mapFragment. Returns a Fragment reference. No problem.
3. We rotate back to Portrait. Check mapFragment. Surprise! It still remembers the Fragment as if it were in the back stack, even though we very consciously cleaned it out.

**Ideas?**

PD: I even tried setting mapFragment equal to null in onStop(). Obviously doesn't work, since this wouldn't be necessary after rotating the screen (we are setting mapFragment from within onCreate, which gets called after every device configuration change).